# Simple question related to double integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to understand something related to Green's theorem application and I need to know something really straight forward. Suppose I have a region $D$ over which I calculate the double integral of $f$. $D$ is composed of of $D_1$ and $D_2$ (both regions are connected like two semi-circles forming a circle). Is it valid that $\iint_D{f\,dA}=\iint_{D1}f\,dA+\iint_{D2}f\,dA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as $D_1$ and $D_2$ are disjoint (or intersect only on a curve). It's just like in the one-dimensional version - $\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx$.